# Node ws with React Native - ws.send is not a function

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, websocket, ws

I am starting to use websockets with ws. So far everything was good. I was playing with ws and react native when this problem occured. I am able to establish connection between client and server but i can't send messages using the ws.send() method. I am building a simple chat app where only specific users can recieve messages.

**Client**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const setws = (path) => {
  ws = new WebSocket(path);
  return ws;
}

export default function App() {
 

  const [serverState, setServerState] = React.useState('Loading...');
  const [messageText, setMessageText] = React.useState('');
  const [disableButton, setDisableButton] = React.useState(true);
  const [inputFieldEmpty, setInputFieldEmpty] = React.useState(true);
  const [serverMessages, setServerMessages] = React.useState([]);

  const [ws, setws] = React.useState('');  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://ip-address:8080');
    const serverMessagesList = [];
    
  
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log("connection opened")
      setServerState('Connected to the server')
      setDisableButton(false);
    };

    ws.onclose = (e) => {
      console.log("connection closed")
      setServerState('Disconnected. Check internet or server.')
      setDisableButton(true);
    };

    ws.onerror = (e) => {
      setServerState(e.message);
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      serverMessagesList.push(e.data);
      setServerMessages([...serverMessagesList])
    };    
  }, [])

  const submitMessage = (ws) => {
    ws.send(messageText);
    setMessageText('')
    setInputFieldEmpty(true)
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#eeceff',
        padding: 5
      }}>
        <Text>{serverState}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{
        backgroundColor: '#ffeece',
        padding: 5,
        flexGrow: 1
      }}>
        <ScrollView>
          {
            serverMessages.map((item, ind) => {
              return (
                <Text key={ind}>{item}</Text>
              )
            })
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <View style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',

      }}>
        <TextInput style={{
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'black',
            flexGrow: 1,
            padding: 5,
          }} 
          placeholder={'Add Message'} 
          onChangeText={text => {
            setMessageText(text)
            setInputFieldEmpty(text.length > 0 ? false : true)  
          }}
          value={messageText}
         />
        <Button
         onPress={submitMessage}
         title={'Submit'} 
         disabled={disableButton || inputFieldEmpty}
        />
      </View>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    paddingTop: 30,
    padding: 8,
  },
  
});
```

**Server**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const server = http.createServer(app);

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

const url = require('url');

//This function generates ids
wss.getUniqueID = function () {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
    return 'USER' + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4();
};

//This function checks if the client is a driver. If not gives an id to the client
wss.checkClient = function (ws) {
    if (ws.id) {
        console.log(ws.id);
    } else {
        if (ws.upgradeReq.url.slice(1)) {
            ws.id = ws.upgradeReq.url.slice(1)}
        else {
            ws.id = wss.getUniqueID();
        }
    }
}
server.listen(8080,'ip-address', () => {
  console.log("Listening to port 8080");
});

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws, req) {
    //Check the id for driver
    wss.checkClient(ws);
    
    console.log("new client connected");

    //We have a connection
    ws.on("message", function incoming(message, isBinary) {
        
        if (ws.id.length > 3) {
            wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                //Check if the user is connected
                if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && client.id == 123) {
                    
                    //Send the message to the user
                    client.send(message.toString());
                }
            });
        } 
    });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
```

I think the problem lays on the client side, but i haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: i think you are not passing ( ws ) .. try console  ws from inside the function , will you get undefined ? make a global ( let ws_global; ) then assign it to new WebSocket, and remove (ws) from the submitMessage function.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to fix the problem. I can bypass the ws.send() problem by initializing the ws outside the useEffect hook like this: const ws = new WebSocket('ws://ip-address:8080'); This way i can send messages, but then every time i type on the app keyboard a new socket is beeing initialized and so a new connection to the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `sumbitMessage` function creates its own `ws` - it is not using your ws state.
2. You use setws twice - once as "global" function, once as setState function.

Just store your created websocket in state and on click pull the state the send function. Just like this:

```
export default function App() {
 

  .....

  const [ws, setWs] = React.useState('');  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    
    const newWs = new WebSocket('ws://ip-address:8080');
    const serverMessagesList = [];
    
  
    newWs.onopen = () => {
      console.log("connection opened")
      setServerState('Connected to the server')
      setDisableButton(false);
    };

    newWs.onclose = (e) => {
      console.log("connection closed")
      setServerState('Disconnected. Check internet or server.')
      setDisableButton(true);
    };

    newWs.onerror = (e) => {
      setServerState(e.message);
    };

    newWs.onmessage = (e) => {
      serverMessagesList.push(e.data);
      setServerMessages([...serverMessagesList])
    };   
   setWs(newWs)  // store created websocket in ws state 
  }, [])

  const submitMessage = (sock) => {
    sock.send(messageText);
    setMessageText('')
    setInputFieldEmpty(true)
  };

.......

        <Button
         onPress={() => submitMessage(ws)}
         title={'Submit'} 
         disabled={disableButton || inputFieldEmpty}
        />
```